# EOM date for various months

Tags: date, excel-formula

I'm looking to get a snapshot of inventory for the latest date of each month.

I.E.

Feb 13
Jan 14
Feb 14

There are duplicate variables - i.e., "a" will be listed several times each month. I need to get a.) the sum of each month (easy), and b.) the snapshot of the last date available.

Part B.) is what I'm having trouble with. I've seen the EOM excel formula - but it requires entering (current, following month, etc.). I just want the formula to spit out the inventory Quantity for the last date of each month, without having to specify which month (current, following, etc.).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if I've interpreted what you're asking correctly, can you do what you want by including the MAX() function? ie    =EOMONTH(MAX(A1:A2),0)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that your data is structured something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF3h0.png

If that is the case, you can use a formula like this:

```
=VLOOKUP(EOMONTH(A12,0),$A$2:$B$5,2,FALSE)
```

Where A12 is the month you want to find the answer for. So the full sheet looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GR5ok.png

As you can see, the formula that I put into cell B12 and then just dragged down is pulling back the correct values for the end of month inventory count. Just populate column A with the month-year you are searching for.

Hope this helps!